# UITextView links highlighting, but not clickable when in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

[image]

I've got these three text views (bottom of the hierarchy) inside a custom tableviewcell.

[image]

Here are their settings. They highlight the right things (phone numbers, addresses, etc) but don't allow me to click them.

Comment: Hi, could you find a solution to this? If so can you please share? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you try manual create your textview. The link below be able to click:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString* cellIdentify = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentify];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentify];
}

UITextView* textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 50)];
textView.text = @"12345678 http://haivl.com";
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
textView.editable = NO;
textView.selectable = YES;
[cell addSubview:textView];
return cell;
```

}

Comment: By this code, every time you will reload the table, a new textView will be added to the cell, without removing the previous one.

Comment: Please subclass the cell and put the textview code in `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 0):

If i m correct, you want to make the interaction with text view...

[ textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES ];

and if you want to make it editable then you can do it by,

textview.editable = Yes;

or bye checking the Editable like this

[image]